# How to get a transaction fee in a Truffle test

Tags: truffle, truffle-test

I would like to test a Solidity function that looks like this and check if a correct amount of ether was sent to a sender:

```
function withdraw() public {
    uint contributed = amounts[msg.sender];
    amounts[msg.sender] = 0;

    msg.sender.send(amounts)
}
```

To implement a test that checks if a particular amount of ether was sent I need to get a subtract balances of an account after a transaction and before a transaction. But to have an accurate check I need to take a transaction fee into account.

Is it possible to get this in a Truffle test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are implementing the test using truffle framework, then truffle transactions return an object that contains gasUsed property:

```
const txnReceipt = await instance.someFunc(someParam);
const gasUsed = txnReceipt.receipt.gasUsed;
```

If you use Ganache as the local test node, you can specify gas price there. Set it as one, and then your eth used is `gasUsed*1 WEI = gasUsed/10^18 ETH`

Answer (score 2):

A mocha reporter for Truffle: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/eth-gas-reporter

#### Install

```
npm install --save-dev eth-gas-reporter
```

#### Truffle config

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    ...etc...
  },
  mocha: {
    reporter: 'eth-gas-reporter',
    reporterOptions : {
      currency: 'CHF',
      gasPrice: 21
    }
  }
};
```